# Mongodb: 'find' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Can you guys help me in resolving this issue. `Client.list_databse_names()` print the list but next line throws following error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 3339,
in __call__self.__name)
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable.
If you meant to call the 'find' method on a 'Database' object it is failing
because no such method exists.
```

Here is the code

```
import pymongo

client =pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://server:password@cluster-sre.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
print(client.list_database_names()) // outputs : ['data', 'admin', 'local']
results = client.locations.find({"city": "Bangalore"})
print(results)
```

Also tried with "client.locations.findOne()" same error message.

Comment: Can you print list of collections and share the output.

Comment: Please check this : https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb

Answer (score 4):

The properties of your `client` object are databases, not collections. So your call should look like this instead:

```
results = client.data.locations.find({"city": "Bangalore"})
```

This assumes `data` is the database where the `locations` collection resides.

Answer (score 1):

The answer JohnnyHK provided addresses the specific issue - you are not specifying the database and/or the collection.  It needs to include both.

Here is a working example of a python file with examples of interactions with MongoDB...

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("replSet/localhost:28017,localhost:28018,localhost:28019", username="myuser", password="mysecret", authSource="admin", authMechanism="SCRAM-SHA-256")

    with client.start_session(causal_consistency = True) as my_session:
        with my_session.start_transaction():

            db = client.mydb
            collection = db.mycollection

            # GET THE COUNT OF DOCUMENTS
            count = collection.count_documents({"firstname": "John"})
            print ("count of documents: " + str(count))

            # ITERATE A QUERY
            for result in collection.find({"firstname": "John"}):
                print ("Iterate a query: " + str(result))

            # INSERT A SINGLE DOCUMENT
            results = collection.insert_one({"firstname": "John"}, session = my_session)
            print ("Insert a single document: inserted id: " + str(results.inserted_id) + ", acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged))

            # INSERT MANY DOCUMENTS (INCLUDE A FIELD CALLED 'number' WITH A RANGE FROM 0 TO 4)
            results = collection.insert_many([{"firstname": "John", "number": i} for i in range(5)], session = my_session)
            print ("Insert a many documents: inserted ids: " + str(results.inserted_ids) + ", acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged))

            # UPDATE ONE (TACK ON ANOTHER FIELD CALLED 'lastname')
            results = collection.update_one({"number": 1}, {"$set": {"lastname": "Doe"}}, session = my_session)
            print ("Update one: acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged) + ", matched_count: " + str(results.matched_count) + ", modified_count: " + str(results.modified_count) + ", upserted_id: " + str(results.upserted_id) + ", raw_result: " + str(results.raw_result))

            # UPSERT ONE (THIS WILL CREATE A DOCUMENT WITH FIELD CALLED 'number' WITH A VALUE OF 23 ALONG WITH FIRST AND LAST NAME FIELDS.
            results = collection.update_one({"number": 23}, {"$set": {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}}, True, session = my_session)
            print ("Upsert one: acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged) + ", matched_count: " + str(results.matched_count) + ", modified_count: " + str(results.modified_count) + ", upserted_id: " + str(results.upserted_id) + ", raw_result: " + str(results.raw_result))

            # UPDATE MANY
            results = collection.update_many({"firstname": "John"}, {"$set": {"city": "Newark"}}, session = my_session)
            print ("Update many: acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged) + ", matched_count: " + str(results.matched_count) + ", modified_count: " + str(results.modified_count) + ", upserted_id: " + str(results.upserted_id) + ", raw_result: " + str(results.raw_result))

            # UPSERT MANY (THIS WILL ONLY INSERT ONE RECORD IF FILTER NOT FOUND, BUT COULD UPDATE MANY)
            results = collection.update_many({"firstname": "John", "middlename": "Jacob"}, {"$set": {"city": "Newark", "state": "Ohio", "number": i} for i in range(5)}, upsert = True, session = my_session)
            print ("Upsert many: acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged) + ", matched_count: " + str(results.matched_count) + ", modified_count: " + str(results.modified_count) + ", upserted_id: " + str(results.upserted_id) + ", raw_result: " + str(results.raw_result))

            # DELETE MANY
            results = collection.delete_many({"firstname": "John"}, session = my_session)
            print ("Delete many: deleted count: " + str(results.deleted_count) + ", acknowledged: " + str(results.acknowledged) + ", raw results: " + str(results.raw_result))
```